# Eine passende Anzeige finden

Tags: meaning, usage, meaning-in-context

Ich möchte nach einer Aufgabe fragen, die ich gemacht habe.
Die Aufgabe ist: Ich muss eine Anzeige finden, die zu der gegebenen Situation passt.

Hier ist die Situation: **Sie sammeln alte Modelleisenbahnen.**

Die folgende Anzeige passt zu der Situation:

```
MODELLEISENBAHNEN,
altes Blechspielzeug, Panzer, Soldaten, Indianer,
Autobahnen, kauft 1070 Wien, Webgasse 15
TEL ....                     Sofortige Barzahlung
```

Meine Frage: **Warum passt die Anzeige zu der Situation?**

Ich habe gedacht, dass die Anzeige aufgebende Person 
Modelleinsenbahnen, usw. **kauft**. Aber meine Situation sagt, ich würde
Modelleinsenbahnen sammeln (also selber kaufen).

Die Aufgabe habe ich aus [diesem Buch](http://books.google.de/books?id=5mSMWNcVK5QC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false).

---

**EDIT**: Ich möchte wissen, **wie man aus der Anzeige findet, 
dass die Anzeige aufgebende Person Modelleisenbahhen verkauft**.

Hypothese 1) Die Anzeige ist typisch.
Falls Sie einige Dinge kaufen und verkaufen wollten,
schreiben Sie oft eine Anzeige, wie diese Anzeige: Etwas, etwas, etwas, kauft ....
(Nach Carlsters Kommentar habe ich diese Idee.)

Hypothese 2) "kauft" bedeutet "Ihr kauft".
(Deshalb ist es möglich, dass die Person der Anzeige nichts kauft.)

Comment: I find the whole exercise slightly confusing, to be honest, but this is clearly a dealer's ad, advertising his desire to buy. Since you, too, are collecting model trains I'm sure he'd be happy to do business with you.

Comment: @Vogel612 Danke Sehr!

Comment: Gern Geschehen. Übrigens würde ich dich gerne in den [Chatraum](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language) einladen. Dort kannst du ein wenig Deutsch üben, sobald du 20 reputation hast. Mehr dazu findest du [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) und [hier](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Inwiefern steht diese Frage im Zusammenhang mit der deutschen Sprache? Dass sie auf Deutsch gestellt wurde ist mir zu wenig. Man kann die Frage in jede beliebige andere Sprache übersetzen und hat bei der Beantwortung mit genau denselben Sachverhalten zu tun. Folglich hat diese Frage nichts mit der Deutschen Sprache an sich zu tun und gehört daher nicht in dieses Forum.

Comment: Man kann die Frage in jede beliebige andere Sprache übersetzen und hat bei der Beantwortung mit genau denselben Sachverhalten zu tun. Folglich hat diese Frage nichts mit der Deutschen Sprache an sich zu tun und gehört daher nicht in ein Forum über Deutsche Sprache.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast This is a sample problem of Leseverstehen of Zertifikat Deutsch and the problem is supposed to require us to understand German language in the Anzeige properly.  If you do not find any relation between my question and German language, you might say "this problem fails to provide a proper exercise".

Comment: I can translate the Anzeige into my mother tongue (by assuming that "kauft" means "(The person of the Anzeige) buys"). Then the Anzeige does not suit the situation. So there is no problem in my mother tongue (if the answer is no suitable Anzeige).

Answer (score -1):

Es gibt verschiedene Gründe Dinge zu sammeln. Als Sammler hat man womöglich Sammlerstücke die man auch bereit ist zu verkaufen, wenn der Preis stimmt. Womöglich um sich mit dem Geld andere Sammelobjekte zu kaufen, die einem mehr am Herzen liegen als das, was man verkauft.

Wer sonst, wenn nicht ein Sammler, sollte einem Käufer solcher Objekte die Modelle verkaufen? Dessen Erben natürlich.